# Android - How to use the ActionBar to navigate between Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-actionbar

New to ActionBar and Fragments but familiar with Android in general.

I have been following a few tutorial. So far I have the following:

- 3 `Fragments` that I want to navigate between (each has an overriden onCreateView() and loads a simple view)
- A custom `TabListener` for the ActionBar (I believe the problem is there, see bottom of post for code)
- A hosting `Activity` in which this is all performed

The Activity code:

```
public class Activity_Home extends Activity
{
ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    actionBar = getActionBar();  // Get reference to ActionBar

    // Add some navigation tabs...

    // 1. Enable ActionBar navigation tabs
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // 2. Add the tabs
    Tab programTab = actionBar.newTab();
    Tab settingsTab = actionBar.newTab();
    Tab historyTab = actionBar.newTab();

    programTab.setText("Program")
              .setTabListener(new TabListener<Fragment_Program>(
                      this, R.id.fragmentParent, Fragment_Program.class));

    settingsTab.setText("Settings")
               .setTabListener(new TabListener<Fragment_Settings>(
                      this, R.id.fragmentParent, Fragment_Settings.class));

    historyTab.setText("History")
      .setTabListener(new TabListener<Fragment_History>(
              this, R.id.fragmentParent, Fragment_History.class));

    actionBar.addTab(programTab);
    actionBar.addTab(settingsTab);
    actionBar.addTab(historyTab);
}
}
```

My Fragments:

```
public class Fragment_Program extends Fragment
{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_program, null);
}
}
```

..

```
public class Fragment_History extends Fragment
{
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, null);
}
}
```

..

```
public class Fragment_Settings extends Fragment
{   
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, null);
}   
}
```

Lastly, my TabListener which has been pretty much based on the official Google example. The fragmentContainer (int) is the XML resource ID of the LinearLayout in the Activities layout that is the direct parent of all of these Fragments.

```
public class TabListener <T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
private Fragment fragment;
private int fragmentContainer;
private final Activity activity;
private final Class<T> fragmentClass;

/** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
 * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
 * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment
 * @param fragmentClass  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
 */
public TabListener(Activity activity, int fragmentContainer, Class<T> fragmentClass)
{
    this.activity = activity;
    this.fragmentContainer = fragmentContainer;
    this.fragmentClass = fragmentClass;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1)
{
    // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.      
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
{
    // Check if the fragment is already intialized
    if (fragment == null)
    {
        // If not, instatiate and add it to the Activity
        fragment = Fragment.instantiate(activity, fragmentClass.getName());

        ft.add(fragmentContainer, fragment);
    }       
    else
    {
        ft.attach(fragment);
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
{
    if (fragment != null)
    {
        // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
        ft.detach(fragment);
    }
}
```

}

So the app loads, the tabs are there, I can select them but they don't seem to be linked to each other and I am not really sure how to proceed.

Any suggestions would be great!

Cheers

BONUS QUESTION: The ActionBar is also below the existing ActionBar.. goal was to replace it, not make another one underneath.. again any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that you want the tabs to be connected in a way that you can swipe between tabs, in order to accomplish this, you should consider a `ViewPager`.

Here's the XML by the way:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's some sample code you can use:

```
public class MyTabActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener  {

  //What item on the pager is being displayed
    private int mCurPagerItem = 0;
  //This will be set to the pageer to handle navigation
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        final ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        //add the tabs
        mActionBar.addTab(mActionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon).setTabListener(this));
        mActionBar.addTab(mActionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon2).setTabListener(this));
        mActionBar.addTab(mActionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon3).setTabListener(this));

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);           

    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Fragment one = new Fragment_Program();
                return one ;
            case 1:
                Fragment two = new Fragment_Settings();
                return two ;
            case 2:
                Fragment three = new Fragment_History();
                return three ;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_one);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_two);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_three);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
        //When a Page is selected, make that the current navigation item
        getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //Back to top maybe?
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //get the position
        final int pos = tab.getPosition();
        //Tell the viewpager to scroll to that page
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
        mCurPagerItem = pos;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
```

To answer your bonus question, on your Manifest, try adding the following line withing the specified activity tag:

```
android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
```

Comment: That isn't really what I am trying to achieve, no page swiping involved. But thank you anyway, appreciate the time and that seems like it may come in handy in the future! Unfortunately that that didn't help the ActionBar either, that split ActionBar half on the top half on the bottom. The problem is I currently have that bar that the soft menu button is located displaying and my ActionBar with the Tabs is directly below.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it!

I changed my approach from using the Fragment Container ID (which did make and does still make more sense to me..) with String tags as per this example [Good complete Fragment and ActionBar example](http://www.lucazanini.eu/2012/android/tab-layout-in-android-with-actionbar-and-fragment/?lang=en) and the official Google example.

Comment: Happy you got it completed then.